# LDAP modifying user info and preventing duplicates

Tags: php, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, ldapconnection

Below is my code for a user modifying their own password. This form works flawlessly. Now the problem here is that I want to user to be able to change their email, phone, or even their name. I use an admin account so it has privleges to search up everyone in LDAP and retrieve all information about everyone. Now the problem is I dont want user's inserting duplicates so if a person with email bobizumi@stackoverflow.com already exists in LDAP then the user shouldnt be allowed to enter this email. Same goes for name and email. I am not sure how to do this search for duplicates, I am assuming it uses ldap_search and ldap_get_entries but I am new to programming with LDAP so I am need some programming assistance on how to go about this. If I can see an example or someone can show me an example with perhaps preventing name duplicate and ldap search with admin privleges then I can go on from there and do the rest on my own but I am just really stuck with the code part and not the logic. I can't find too many examples out there on documentation of ldap and its integration and functionality with PHP or any code snippets so I am stuck trying thigns from PHP manual.

PHP:

```
function changePassword($server,$dn,$user,$oldPassword,$newPassword,$newPasswordCnf){
  global $message;

  error_reporting(0);

  $con=ldap_connect($server);
  ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

  $findWhat = array ("cn","mail","*");
  $findWhere = $dn;
  $findFilter = "(uid=$user)";

  #bind anon and find user by uid
  $sr = ldap_search($con,$dn,$findFilter,$findWhat);
  $records = ldap_get_entries($con, $sr);
  // echo "<pre>";print_r($records);
  /* error if found more than one user */
  if ($records["count"] != "1") {
    $message[] = "Error E100 - Wrong user.";
    return false; 
  }else {
    $message[] = "Found user <b>".$records[0]["cn"][0]."</b>";
  }

  /* try to bind as that user */
  if (ldap_bind($con, $records[0]["dn"], $oldPassword) === false) {
    $message[] = "Error E104 - Current password is wrong.";
    return false;
  }
  else {    echo"TEST";
  $sr = ldap_search($con,$dn,$findFilter,$findWhat);
  $records = ldap_get_entries($con, $sr);
   echo "<pre>";print_r($records);
   }

  if ($newPassword != $newPasswordCnf ) {
    $message[] = "Error E101 - New passwords do not match! ";
    return false;
  }
  if (strlen($newPassword) < 8 ) {
    $message[] = "Error E102 - Your new password is too short! ";
    return false;
  }
  if (!preg_match("/[0-9]/",$newPassword)) {
    $message[] = "Error E103 - Your password must contain at least one digit. ";
    return false;
  }
  if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/",$newPassword)) {
    $message[] = "Error E103 - Your password must contain at least one letter. ";
    return false;
  }






  $entry = array();
  $entry["userPassword"] = "{SHA}" . base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( $newPassword ) ) );
  if (ldap_modify($con,$records[0]["dn"],$entry) === false){
    $message[] = "E200 - Your password cannot be change, please contact the administrator.";
  }
  else { 
    $message[] = " Your password has been changed. "; 
    //mail($records[0]["mail"][0],"Password change notice : ".$user,"Your password has just been changed."); 
    } 
}  

?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Change your password</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font-family: Verdana,Arial,Courier New; font-size: 0.7em;  }
 input:focus { background-color: #eee; border-color: red; }
 th { text-align: right; padding: 0.8em; }
 #container { text-align: center; width: 500px; margin: 5% auto; } 
 ul { text-align: left; list-style-type: square; } 
 .msg { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; color: navy;  border-top: 1px solid red;  border-bottom: 1px solid red;  } 
 </style>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2> Change your LDAP password </h2>
<ul>
  <li> Your new password must be 8 characters long and contain at least one letter and one digit. </li>

</ul>
<form method="post">
  <table style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr><th>Username:</th><td><input name="username" type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th>Old password:</th><td><input name="oldPassword" type="password" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th>New password:</th><td><input name="newPassword1" type="password" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th>New password (confirm):</th><td><input name="newPassword2" type="password" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;" ><input name="submitted" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div class="msg">
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) {
  $rdn = sprintf($dn,$_POST["username"]); 
  changePassword($server,$dn,$_POST["username"],$_POST["oldPassword"],$_POST["newPassword1"],$_POST["newPassword2"]);
  foreach ( $message as $one ) { echo "<p>$one</p>"; }
} 
?>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLDAP has a 'uniqueness' overlay designed for exactly this. You load it via slapd.conf and configure which attributes you require to be unique.

Answer (score -1):

Ldap doesn't support unique constraints on fields except for the distinguished name.  You can search on those fields and use an or condition to do it in one query but you will not be 100% protected.  Two people could submit the same values at the same time and the timing could be just right that duplicates could occur.  Here's a filter example that will search on name or email.

```
(|(&(givenname=joe)(sn=smith))(mail=joe.smith@example.com))
```

If you get a hit you have a possible duplicate.